# Track a fix area with meanshift -OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I need your help in OpenCV. I'm a student and am working on a project in which involves a little autonomous car. I use Python for the main programming language.

I have some problem with my meanshift.  When I run the program, I want the camera fixed on an area on the floor and stay on this area.  I would like for the car to drive alone while following the floor, and I don't want that meanshift to find another object different from the floor.

The program works well, but not optimally for the floor.  Do you have a solution or a way to proceed?

```
def camshift(frame1,frame2,trackWindow) :
    points=[]
    size1=frame1.shape[0] #width
    size2=frame1.shape[1] #length
    #hsv referentiel
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    #Mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,np.array((0., 60.,32.)), np.array((180.,255.,255.)))
    x0, y0, w, h = trackWindow

    trackWindow1=[x0,y0,w,h]
    x1 = x0 + w -1
    y1 = y0 + h -1

    hsv_roi = hsv[y0:y1, x0:x1]
    mask_roi = mask[y0:y1, x0:x1]
    #compute histogram for that area
    hist = cv2.calcHist( [hsv_roi], [0], mask_roi, [16], [0, 180] )
    #Normalisation 
    cv2.normalize(hist, hist, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX);
    hist_flat = hist.reshape(-1)
    points.append(hsv)
    prob = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv,cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv.CV_BGR2HSV)],[0],hist_flat,  [0,180],1)
    prob &= mask
    term_crit = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1 )
    #checking conditions not to go out of bounds
    if (trackWindow[0] < 0) :
        trackWindow[0] = 0
    if (trackWindow[1] < 0) :
        trackWindow[1] = 0
    if (trackWindow[0]+trackWindow[3] >= size1) :
        trackWindow1.append(size1-y0)
        w=trackWindow1[4]
        trackWindow1.pop()
    if (trackWindow[0]+trackWindow[2] >= size2) :
        trackWindow1.append(size2-x0)
        h=trackWindow1[4]
        trackWindow1.pop()
    x0, y0, w, h = trackWindow
    if (trackWindow[0]+trackWindow[2])<100 : 
        trackWindow = (125,125,200,100) 
    if (trackWindow[1]+trackWindow[3])<100 : 
        trackWindow = (125,125,200,100) 
    # self.ellipse, trackWindow = cv2.CamShift(prob, trackWindow, term_crit)

    new_ellipse, track_window = cv2.CamShift(prob,trackWindow, term_crit)
    #we draw the rectangle on the relevant area
     cv2.rectangle(frame1, (trackWindow[0],trackWindow[1]), (trackWindow[0]+trackWindow[2],trackWindow[1]+trackWindow[3]), color=(255,0,0))

    cv2.imshow("mask",mask)
    return track_window
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Code Review! What do you mean by "not optimally for the floor"? We focus on improving working code: code reviews will not change the behaviour, only do the same thing in a better way. Sorry if you were misled on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace. Use it. It makes code *much* clearer. Here's a list of places where you can add whitespace to make your code clearer.

1. `(frame1,frame2,trackWindow) :` \$\rightarrow\$ `(frame1, frame2, trackWindow):`
2. `trackWindow1=[x0,y0,w,h]` \$\rightarrow\$ `trackWindow1 = [x0, y0, w, h]`
3. `( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1 )` \$\rightarrow\$ `(cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1)`
4. `cv2.imshow("mask",mask)` \$\rightarrow\$ `cv2.imshow("mask", mask)`

There are many other places like this in your code, so I'm going to recommend looking at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's official style guide, on how to correct these.

Finally, in all your `if` conditions, are just `if` conditions. If you're not using `elif`, then all of these conditions will be evaluated if they are true. Are you sure that you want this?